# Get matched String in R using grepl

Tags: r, regex

I was trying to get matched strings using Grepl.

**Code**

```
dt_test <- data.frame(
                a = c("ab","abcd", "poo", "abla", "ba"),
                id = c(1,2,3, 4,5)
)
grepl('^ab|^ao', dt_test$a)
```

What it returns was `TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE` But I want ro print Matched strings like `"ab","abcd", "abla"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep` with the `value` switch set to true:

```r
grep('^a[bo]', dt_test$a, value=TRUE)

[1] "ab"   "abcd" "abla"
```